# If two rigid bodies contact with a plane surface in balance, is the normal force uniformly distributed on the contacted surface?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

The normal force may be unevenly distributed on the surface of contact between two bodies. I had a discussion with my friend but was unable to prove whether this assertion is true or false under two RIGID bodies. I know it is a unreal question. Therefore, I am seeking a mathematical solution to this question.  (If this question is independent from classical mechanics, how to prove?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plank overhanging off a building — where does the normal force go?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/764869/)

Comment: If the pressure is not uniform, how would it be nonuniformly distributed? All points on a planar surface are equivalent. As noted in the linked question that seems to be a functional duplicate, the problem is statically indeterminate (i.e., various combinations of point and distributed normal loads would satisfy the equations of equilibrium), but the simplest and most reasonable solution is a uniform pressure.